# gtk gl_area_queue_render is preventing treeview refresh

Tags: c++, gtk3

First of all, I am pretty new to GTK, so I might be missing something obvious.

I have a simple setup :
a gtk_application displaying 2 gtk_application_windows , one containing a button and a treeview widget, and the other one contains just a gl_area.

the "clicked" signal for the button fires a function to add an element to the list displayed by the treeview.

My issue is : the treeview content is never refreshed. That is, as long as gl_area is continuously updated, which I need.

I added :

```
gtk_gl_area_queue_render(gl_area);
```

at the end of my gl_area_render function.
If I comment this line, the treeview updates correctly.

I have tried many different solutions to go around the problem, but nothing works for now.
Another weird thing is :  if I minimize the window displaying opengl data, it somehow triggers as refresh of the treeview, and new entries are displayed as needed.

I almost forgot ... I am on a raspberrypi 3 using 'buster', maybe it's part of the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a bug on Raspberry Pi.
I tried the exact same setup on Win10 and it works like a charm.